# Does the Grails "war" command minify JavaScript files?

Tags: grails, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a Grails application building in an AWS CodePipeline.  We recently upgraded from Grails 4 to Grails 5 and now one of the third-party JavaScript packages we use is having a problem because it's being minified somewhere in the build process, but the minification process is not properly renaming a particular variable in all parts of the js file.  I'd like to switch the minify option in our build process to whitespace only in order to prevent the js variable names from being renamed/shortened.  In my local builds, I use the asset-pipeline plugin in build.gradle to minify the js files and I set the optimization level to whitespace only...which works great...but I'm not sure where/how to do that in the AWS CodePipeline.

In the buildspec.yml file being used in the codepipeline, we are simply installing Grails 5 and then issuing the following command:  `/root/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin/grails war -Dgrails.env=$GRAILS_ENVIRONMENT`

Someone on the team thought the Grails war command might be responsible for the js minification, but I haven't been able to find anything.  Hence my question here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The minification does occur during the WAR creation.  I had to add the following code to the application.groovy file in order to minify whitespace only.

```
grails.assets.minifyOptions = [
    optimizationLevel: 'WHITESPACE_ONLY' //SIMPLE, ADVANCED or WHITESPACE_ONLY
```

]

I also had to modify the problematic js file by adding a comment to it in order to force that file to be re-compiled.

https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html